# Move cursor to Start of document/End of document on OSX

Tags: osx

On Linux, I am able to move the cursor to start of buffer/end of buffer using using C-Home/C-End respectively:

```
C-End       Move cursor to the end of the buffer. Note the key is 'End' key on the keyboard.
C-Home      Move cursor to the beginning of the buffer.
```

However, on Mac OSX, I am unable to perform this simple operation. First, there is no HOME or END key. Second, supposedly, these keys are supposed to be the substitute:

```
begin   M-<     ⌘↑
end     M->     ⌘↓
```

But M-< and M-> are reserved for something else. And ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ are undefined. Only experience this issue with OSX. How should I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried binding the keys you want to what you want them to be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use `fn left-arrow` and `fn right-arrow` to invoke `home` and `end`?

Answer (score 1):

What `M-<` and `M->` are reserved for in your config? By default (`emacs -Q`) they are bound to `beginning-of-buffer` and `end-of-buffer` respectively. Even if they bound to something else, you can make ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ do the work:

```elisp
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<up>") #'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<down>") #'end-of-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

`M-<` and `M->` should work unless bound otherwise. I usually test things using `F1` help key `F1-k` which should prompt you for the key binding to test, in this case enter M-< and see what it is bound to, if anything.

For me, I get:

```
⌥< (translated from <escape> <) runs the command beginning-of-buffer
(found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to <home>, <A-up>, <A-prior>, <kp-home>, <begin>, ⌥<,
<menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <beg-of-buf>.

(beginning-of-buffer &optional ARG)

This function is for interactive use only;
in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-min))' instead.

Move point to the beginning of the buffer.
With numeric arg N, put point N/10 of the way from the beginning.
If the buffer is narrowed, this command uses the beginning of the
accessible part of the buffer.

Push mark at previous position, unless either a ^U prefix
is supplied, or Transient Mark mode is enabled and the mark is active.
```